# Use a package spec inside a procedure

Tags: ada

I want to use a package spec inside a procedure.

Something is missing for that, but i don't know what.

> using_ads_package.adb:14:11: "var" is not visible
>
> using_ads_package.adb:14:11: non-visible declaration at line 8

```
with Ada.Strings.Unbounded; use Ada.Strings.Unbounded;
with Ada.Text_IO.Unbounded_IO;  use Ada.Text_IO.Unbounded_IO;

Procedure using_ads_package is

   Package variable is

      var : Unbounded_String ;
  
   end variable ;

Begin
 
   get_line(var);
 
End using_ads_package ;
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In

```
procedure Using_Ads_Package is
   package Variable is
      Var : Unbounded_String;
   end Variable;
begin
```

you’ve created a new scope in `package Variable`. Outside `Variable`, `Var` isn’t directly visible.

Outside `Variable`, you have two ways of referring to `Var`.

First, you can name the package in which it’s declared explicitly:

```
   Get_Line (Variable.Var);
```

Alternatively, you can `use` `Variable`:

```
   package Variable is
      Var : Unbounded_String;
   end Variable;
   use Variable;
begin
   Get_Line (Var);
```

Answer (score 1):

Without compiling I’d suggest that the line:

```
 get_line(var);
```

should be:

```
 get_line(variable.var);
```